# Microsoft jet skips 90 records

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have a database that contains 5000 records. I have the first 1000 that were used without a hitch. However, the next 90 records, the JET driver simply skips these for seemingly no reason.

I am not sure what the cause of this is. I don't think that the issue is my SQL command. However, I am posting it here in the event there there is. Note: I know that adding strings together for the sql command is not a good idea but I am only able to get this to work by doing it this way.

```
string queryTest = "Select Serial_Number FROM serialNumbers WHERE Is_Used=false AND (In_Progress=false OR Accessed_Time_Stamp < #" + testTime.ToString() + "#);";
```

Please, if there is any way that I can replace `testTime.ToString()` to @time and then call `setCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", testTime.ToString());` Please let me know. So far, this has been throwing exceptions.

Back to the main question. So there is this group that JET skips that is 90 records long. I ma not sure why and I was wondering if anyone here knew what might be causing this.

I should also mention that I recently merged this table with another in order to create the 5000 records. Yes, this issue is happening right at the first 90 numbers that the merge took place at. Also, the ID jumps for 1000 to 1002. Not sure if this will have any effect but I wanted to mention it.

Also, I am coding this in C#.

Comment: Are you sure they are being skipped entirely, or are they just out of order? You have no order specified in the query, and they could easily be out of order if you've just merged them somehow.

Comment: In the database, they are in the correct order. This is a MS Access database that I have created and I can view the database in MS Access. I used this query command on a previous set of 100  for testing and it was able to grab the serial numbers without any issue. Although, it could be because the 100 were in order from 1 to 100. But I look at the ID for the current database and it too is also in order by ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the issue that you are seeing is that although the database is displaying the numbers in order, there could be an internal reference that is causing the serial numbers to be referenced out of order. As DancingFool suggested, you should make sure that you have an ORDER BY operation to sort the database when you request a serial number. Try it with this code:

```
string queryTest = "Select Serial_Number FROM serialNumbers WHERE Is_Used=false AND (In_Progress=false OR Accessed_Time_Stamp < #" + testTime.ToString() + "#) ORDER BY ID ASC;";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameter by declaring your SQL statement to be:

```
PARAMETERS AccessTimeStampParam DateTime;
SELECT Serial_Number
  FROM serialNumbers
 WHERE Is_Used = false
   AND (In_Progress = false OR Accessed_Time_Stamp < [AccessTimeStampParam]);
```

And then pass in a value for the `AccessTimeStampParam` parameter.